# Unable to connect to flask while running on docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to move a simple flask application to docker, but I can't see to figure out why the application is not accessible from the browser.

#### docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: api
      FLASK_ENV: development

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

#### dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

#### __init__py:

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
  app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
  ...

  return app
```

#### result from docker-compose up --build

```
web_1    |  * Serving Flask app "api" (lazy loading)
web_1    |  * Environment: development
web_1    |  * Debug mode: on
web_1    |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
web_1    |  * Restarting with stat
web_1    |  * Debugger is active!
web_1    |  * Debugger PIN: 277-205-758
```

But when I got to the browser:

`The connection was reset`

[image]

Any ideas why? I can't see what I am missing because the server is running but it does reset the connection right away...

#### Edit:

- I did try to access it via localhost, 0.0.0.0, also using the container IP address

Comment: Try to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: did that, also try to get point directly to the container IP address, still same issue with the connection being reset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Okay that just blow my mind, why is that parameter required while running on docker but not when running from the normal terminal?

Comment: You're connecting to flask from outside the container, so because of that boundary crossing, the request isn't "local". 0.0.0.0 lets flask answer to non-local requests.

Comment: I tried using this but didn't work. message shown on web page is "This page isn’t working 0.0.0.0 didn’t send any data".